# BarButtonItemにSentEventのTouchUpInsideは設定できますか？

Tags: swift

いつもお世話になっております。
表題の通りです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑登録ボタン（TourokuButton）に画像のような設定をしたいです。
（この画像はUIButton）のものです。

ですが、BarButtonItemでは、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑こうなります。
UITextFieldに入力項目がキチンと入力されていないとButtonを押せないような設定をしたいのですが、BarButtonItemでは不可能なのでしょうか？

お解りになる方がいらっしゃればご教授下さい。
お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Touch Up Inside`や`Editing Changed`は[`UIControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/)由来の機能なので、[`UIBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/)では利用できません。

`UIBarButtonItem`がなぜ`UIControl`継承ではないかというと、`UIBarButtonItem`そのものはボタンのようなUI要素ではなく、「バーに表示されるボタンやその他の要素」を抽象化したクラスだからです。

> UITextFieldに入力項目がキチンと入力されていないとButtonを押せないような設定をしたいのですが、BarButtonItemでは不可能なのでしょうか？

実現したいことはこちらだと思うのですが、`UIBarButtonItem`を`Referencing Outlet`で紐付けているのですから、条件に応じて`self.tourokuButton`の`enabled`プロパティを変更すれば良いと思います。

Comment: アドバイスいただきまして有難うございました。